# How to verify a particular text is present inside a log (String format) in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xctest

let command = // some shell command execution that prints some log in terminal

command.description //This gives me the String representation

let textToSearch = "some string value "

//My approaches

let status = command.description.conatains(textToSearch)

XCTAssert(status, "The Text is not present!") // Fail

let status2 = command.description.range(of: textToSearch) != nil

XCTAssert(status, "The Text is not present!") // Fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let command = Foo()
let description = command.description
let textToSearch = "some string value"
let status = description.localizedLowercase.contains(textToSearch.localizedLowercase)

XCTAssertTrue(status, "The Text is not present!")
```